# use django model's field value inside href tag in template

Tags: python, django

Here the issue that I am facing. Let's say I have a model with two field. Field1 is a string value and Field2 one contains a url link. I want  to render Field1 and the user can click on Field1 and gets redirected to template at Field2 url.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
<td>{{class.Class}}<a href="{{ class.extra_details_view }}"></a></td>
#class = Field1
#extra_detail_view = Field2 (link)
```

this renders `Class` values just fine but does not let me click it.
I don't know what else to try to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can use a simple string formatting technique here,

```
model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=123)

foo = f'<a href="{model_instance.url_field}">{model_instance.string_field}</a>'
```

or you can do the same in templates as

```
<a href="{{ model_instance.url_field }}">{{ model_instance.string_field }}</a>
```

Comment: thank you for you response, I am not quite understanding it, are you suggesting to write foo as such in my view?